# Partition without flatten in BigQuery

Tags: google-bigquery

Consider the following schema which contains transaction_no, date when it was created(created_at) & Items(RECORD):

```
[
   {
      "mode":"REQUIRED",
      "name":"Id",
      "type":"INTEGER"
   },
   {
      "fields":[
         {
            "mode":"REQUIRED",
            "name":"Name",
            "type":"STRING"
         },
         {
            "mode":"REQUIRED",
            "name":"Qty",
            "type":"INTEGER"
         }
      ],
      "mode":"REPEATED",
      "name":"Items",
      "type":"RECORD"
   },
   {
      "mode":"REQUIRED"
      "name":"Transaction_no",
      "type":"STRING"
   },
   {
      "mode":"REQUIRED",
      "name":"Created_at",
      "type":"TIMESTAMP"
   }
]
```

Since this table contains, same item again, I use window function to grab the last item based on the transaction_no & ordered by created_at like this to dump into another table:

```
SELECT *
FROM (
  SELECT * 
  ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY transaction_no 
                    ORDER BY created_at DESC) as last
  FROM my_dataset.my_table
)
WHERE last = 1
```

Unfortunately this has following problems.

1. this flattens the `Items` record. I have flatten result checkbox unselected
2. It seems it only picks the first field from each repeatable record.

What I want to do here is Remove duplicates without changes the table structure. Possible?

Comment: Make this a view and query the view instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In assumption that your real case is as simple as your example (*in terms of schema*) and that you have unique key to reassemble original records (*looks like you do have such - transaction_no*) - the most efficient/optimal way to do this (on my taste) is :
  1. flatten out your data
  2. perform all you aggregation / grouping logic
  3. recreate initial schema using NEST()
Should be pretty simple to make all in one nice query

Another option  - If you have time to experiment - you can try play with `OMIT … IF` clause
Note that it can be used not only in form of `OMIT RECORD IF` but also in form of
`OMIT {non-leaf node} IF`. This latter form can be used to eliminate some entries in your repeated field based on required condition `OMIT Items IF condition`
You can read more on this https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/query-reference#omit

In your particular case I suggest to go with first option as it is more straightforward and relatively simple to implement